# How do I take differences of two rows based on conditional statement?

Tags: r

I'm having a lot of trouble with this really easy problem. Below is a sample of my data:

```
            EUR.20MA.1 EUR.LAST.2
2013-11-04          1     1.3514
2013-11-05         -1     1.3474
2013-11-06          1     1.3513
2013-11-07          0     1.3419
2013-11-08         -1     1.3367
2013-11-11          1     1.3407
```

Basically whenever the signal changes from 1 to 0, or 1 to -1, I want to take the difference of that row with the subsequent row. Hence, output would look like:

```
         EUR.20MA.1 EUR.LAST.2  Difference  
11/4/2013   1       1.3514      0.004
11/5/2013  -1       1.3474      0
11/6/2013   1       1.3513      0.0094
11/7/2013   0       1.3419      0   
11/8/2013  -1       1.3367      0   
11/11/2013  1       1.3407      0   
11/12/2013  1       1.3436      0   
11/13/2013  1       1.3487      0.0026
11/14/2013 -1       1.3461      0
```

Dput below:

```
structure(list(EUR.20MA.1 = c(1, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1
), EUR.LAST.2 = c(1.3514, 1.3474, 1.3513, 1.3419, 1.3367, 1.3407, 
1.3436, 1.3487, 1.3461, 1.3496)), .Names = c("EUR.20MA.1", "EUR.LAST.2"
), row.names = c("2013-11-04", "2013-11-05", "2013-11-06", "2013-11-07", 
"2013-11-08", "2013-11-11", "2013-11-12", "2013-11-13", "2013-11-14", 
"2013-11-15"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Not really sure why I got downvoted without a reason. Thanks to everyone below for answering though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this in base R:

```
a <- which(df$EUR.20MA.1==1)
b <- which(df$EUR.20MA.1 %in% c(0,-1))
rws <- sapply(b, function(x) any(a==x-1))
df$Difference <- 0
df[b[rws]-1,]$Difference <- abs(df[b[rws]-1,]$EUR.LAST.2 - df[b[rws],]$EUR.LAST.2)

           # EUR.20MA.1 EUR.LAST.2 Difference
# 2013-11-04          1     1.3514     0.0040
# 2013-11-05         -1     1.3474     0.0000
# 2013-11-06          1     1.3513     0.0094
# 2013-11-07          0     1.3419     0.0000
# 2013-11-08         -1     1.3367     0.0000
# 2013-11-11          1     1.3407     0.0000
# 2013-11-12          1     1.3436     0.0000
# 2013-11-13          1     1.3487     0.0026
# 2013-11-14         -1     1.3461     0.0000
# 2013-11-15          1     1.3496     0.0000
```

So you first find the rows where `1` is appeared and assign them to `a`. Then you search for rows in which `0` or `-1` is appeared and assign them to `b`. Then search for sequence numbers in `a` or `b` which are those rows you look after.

---

OR use this (following the idea of @Lamia to multiply `df$EUR.20MA.1` by 2):

```
df$Difference <- c(head(df$EUR.LAST.2, -1) - tail(df$EUR.LAST.2, -1), 0)
df[!c(with(df, (2*head(EUR.20MA.1, -1) - tail(EUR.20MA.1, -1)) %in% c(2,3)), FALSE),] <- 0
```

which will give you the same result.

Comment: Thank you! I might end up going with @Lamia's code. I appreciate that you have a solution for base R though. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Using the `lead` function from the `dplyr` package,

you can do:

```
library(dplyr)
df$Difference=df[,2]-lead(df[,2],1)
df$Difference[(2*df[,1]-lead(df[,1],1))<2]=0
# The multiplication by 2 is to differentiate between 1 followed by 0 and 0 followed by -1
```

Comment: Wow, this was a really smart write-up. Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

A lengthier dplyr version, using lags instead of leads and results on the next row.

```
library(dplyr)
df <- st %>%
  mutate(EUR.20MA.1_lag = lag(EUR.20MA.1),
         EUR.LAST.2_lag = lag(EUR.LAST.2),
         signal = (EUR.20MA.1_lag == 1 & EUR.20MA.1 == 0) |  
                  (EUR.20MA.1_lag == 1 & EUR.20MA.1 == -1),
         difference = if_else(signal, EUR.LAST.2 - EUR.LAST.2_lag, 0))

df

#    EUR.20MA.1 EUR.LAST.2 EUR.20MA.1_lag EUR.LAST.2_lag signal difference
# 1           1     1.3514             NA             NA  FALSE     0.0000
# 2          -1     1.3474              1         1.3514   TRUE    -0.0040
# 3           1     1.3513             -1         1.3474  FALSE     0.0000
# 4           0     1.3419              1         1.3513   TRUE    -0.0094
# 5          -1     1.3367              0         1.3419  FALSE     0.0000
# 6           1     1.3407             -1         1.3367  FALSE     0.0000
# 7           1     1.3436              1         1.3407  FALSE     0.0000
# 8           1     1.3487              1         1.3436  FALSE     0.0000
# 9          -1     1.3461              1         1.3487   TRUE    -0.0026
# 10          1     1.3496             -1         1.3461  FALSE     0.0000
```